# Set javascript variable from Ruby partial

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, partial

I have a very long operation that ends in a huge array.  That array is passed as a Ruby object to a js.erb file which renders a partial using it:

```
$('#xxx').html("<%= escape_javascript(render('part', testVar: @fromServer)) %>");
```

This all goes well, but I'd like to be able to sort columns in the resulting table without having to re-do the entire operation.  It should be easy, but I can't get the resulting variable in the partial to persist.  My goal is to be able to have a script tag in the partial:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#column").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
              type : 'POST',
              url : '/sort_column',
              data : {data: jsVar},
              dataType : 'script'
        });
    });
</script>
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap what you need from ruby in <%= %>. Like that:

```
data : {data: "<%= testVar %>"},
```

Since document will be send to ruby interpreter it will contain your testVar value. Also please use snake case notation instead of camel case. It's common agreement in ruby.

Comment: For whatever reason, the script just isn't being rendered.  Is there some rule in Ruby about rendering scripts in partials?

Comment: If you don't getting errors then probably your controller logic works not as expected and not responding with js, could you add controller method to the question?